# Filtering and grouping in list based on condition

Tags: list, vb.net, linq

I have a list object with properties

```
[
   {
      "Id": 123,
      "Name": "Admin",
      "Group": 1,
      "OldValue": 2,
      "LastestValue": 1
   },
   {
      "Id":123,
      "Name": "Admin",
      "Group": 1,
      "OldValue": 0,
      "LastestValue": 1
   },
   {
      "Id": 456,
      "Name": "Worker",
      "Group": 2,
      "OldValue": 0,
      "LastestValue": 1
   }
]
```

I'm able to extract data based on `Name`.

```vb
Dim result = myList.GroupBy(Function(i) i.Name).Where(Function(p) p.Count >1).SelectMany(Function(k) k).ToList()
```

But doing as above way I missed out the `Id`: 456 values. I want to filter out the entries and do a condition check, for the name like "Admin", I want to compare its first `record.LastestValue` vs last `record.LastestValue` if they match, save the last record item entry and disregard anything else and also preserve the records that don't have name with count > 1.

Expected result:

```
[
   {
      "Id": 123,
      "Name": "Admin",
      "Group": 1,
      "OldValue": 0,
      "LastestValue": 1
   },
   {
      "Id": 456,
      "Name": "Worker",
      "Group": 2,
      "OldValue": 0,
      "LastestValue": 1
   }
]
```

Comment: Your syntax is VB.NET. You are tagging the C#, are you expecting the answer written in C#?

Comment: "First" and "Last" aren't well-defined here. Don't expect `GroupBy` to gurantee that the original order in the collection is preserved. Also, what if multiple `LatestValue`s of the same names do *not* match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You are tagging the C# and assume that you are accepting the C# answer.*

Within each group, you can add logic to check that the `LastestValue` of both first and last records are the same. This works fine too for the group with single record as the first and last record will refer to the same record.

If the condition unmet, returns `null` and ensure that you need to remove the records which are `null` for the result.

```cs
var result = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Select(g => new
                    {
                        Name = g.Key,
                        Data = g.First().LastestValue == g.Last().LastestValue
                            ? g.Last()
                            : null
                    })
            .Select(x => x.Data)
            .Where(x => x != null)
            .ToList();
```

For VB.NET it should be:

```vb
Dim result = myList.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Name).Select(
            Function(g) New With {
                Key.Name = g.Key, 
                Key.Data = If(g.First().LastestValue = g.Last().LastestValue, g.Last(), Nothing)
            }).Select(Function(x) x.Data).Where(Function(x) x IsNot Nothing).ToList()
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pYJ6j6)

Comment: [Demo (VB.NET) @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jJBds2)

Comment: [
   {
   ""Id"": 123,
   ""Name"": ""Admin"",
   ""Group"": 1,
   ""OldValue"": 0,
   ""LastestValue"": 1
   },
   {""Id"": 123,
   ""Name"": ""Admin"",
   ""Group"": 1,
   ""OldValue"": 1,
   ""LastestValue"": 0
   },
   {""Id"": 123,
   ""Name"": ""Admin"",
   ""Group"": 1,
   ""OldValue"": 1,
   ""LastestValue"": 1
   },
   {""Id"": 456,
   ""Name"": ""Worker"",
   ""Group"": 2,
   ""OldValue"": 0,
   ""LastestValue"": 1
   }]";
Expected result: is last element of 123 and 456 item (2 items)

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't do it right if there are mulitple items.

 Loop over the same name, compare first element.LatestValue == last element.LatestValue, if both are equal, take last element(disregard other ones) plus include the ungrouped ones (individual names).

Ex: Name with Admin can have multiple items, similarly Name with Tester can have multiple items, all should extract last item, if its (admin.firstRecord.Latest=admin.lastRecordLatest), similarly for (tester.firstRecord.Latest=tester.lastRecordLatest)

Comment: What if within the group, the first record's `LastestValue` and the last record's `LastestValue` are not the same, the data should be excluded? Like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pYJ6j6) and for [VB.NET](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jJBds2)